# My alert doesn't show up in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This is my alert.blade.php,

```
@if(Session::has('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('info') }}</div>
@endif
```

And this is my welcome.blade.php,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"     integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"     crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        @include('alert')
    </body>
</html>
```

And, here's my routes.php,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome')->with('info','Hello World');
});
```

Any help will be really appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`return view('welcome')->with('info','Hello World');`

This line returns the value of 'info' to the view and doesn't set it to the session. While your code:

```
@if(Session::has('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('info') }}</div>
@endif
```

checks whether there exists a `info` variable in the session or not. So you need to change your view to:

```
@if(isset($info))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ $info }}</div>
@endif
```

Which basically would check if the view has a variable called `info` and if it is true, it prints its value.

Answer (score -1):

Using `->with()` will result in a accesible variable inside your view.

You can choose to change it to:

```
@if (isset($info))
```

However there are some other cleaner ways to solve this.

You can use the function `withErrors()`

It would look like:

```
return view('yourView')->withErrors(['info' => 'Your message'])
```

And you can access it like:

```
@if ($errors->has('info'))

    {{ $errors->first('info') }}

@endif
```